# Haskell Persistent: Is possible to select all rows by field that contains specified value

Tags: haskell, persistent

I have following Persistent model

```
Tag
    name String
    description String
    UniqueName name

Post
    caption String
    text    String
    created UTCTime
    tags    [TagId]
    deriving Show
```

Is possible to select all posts that contains specified `TagId` in field `tags`? Or i need to create new model to handle many-to-many relationship?

PS Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No since list-like columns are not part of SQL.

Practically, your `tags` column is defined as `"tags" VARCHAR NOT NULL` in SQLite.

If you want to run any kind of non-trivial queries on your `Post` I would strongly recommend, as you said, to redesign your schema.

Removing `tags` from `Post` and adding the following table should allow you to get all posts of a specific tag.

```hs
TagPost
    tagId TagId
    postId PostId
    UniqueTagPost tagId postId
```

```hs
λ> tagPosts <- selectList [TagPostTagId ==. yourTagId] []
```

You might also want to take a look at [Esqueleto](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto), it will allow you to write type safe joins (stuff that `persistent` does not provide by default since it must stay compatible with MongoDB).